# Ассинхронность Kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy

У меня стоит задача, что мне нужно сделать приложение на kivy, чтобы в какой-то момент асинхронно запускался sleep на n секунд и по завершению включался звук с помощью playsound
Меня интересует - как можно сделать, чтобы при работе приложения(MainApp.run()) параллельно работал метод sleep? При разнообразных вариантах вылетала ошибка

Comment: попробуйте Clock.schedule_once()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `sleep` не подходит для этой задачи. Для этого Вам нужно использовать [kivy.clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html).

Вот пример из документации, где после ожидания выполняется функция без аргументов:

```
def no_args_func():
    print("I accept no arguments, so don't schedule me in the clock")

Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: no_args_func(), 0.5)
```

Comment: Спасибо, все сработало!